# Invalid operands to binary expressions

Tags: recursion, backtracking, n-queens

I was solving N queens problem and I wrote `isvalid` function, but the function gives "invalid operands to binary expressions" error. The error occurs at `board[X][Y] == 'Q'`:

```
 bool isvalid(vector<vector<string>>& board , int &row , int &col , int &n){
   
    int x = row ;
    int y = col ;
    while(y >= 0){
        if(board[x][y] == 'Q'){// THE ERROR IS OCCURING HERE AT BOARD[X][Y]== 'Q' 
            return false; 
        }
        y--  ;
    }
    int x = row ;
    int y = col ;
    while(x >=0 and y>=0){
        if(board[x][y] == 'Q')return false; 
        x-- ;
        y-- ;
    }
    int x = row ;
    int y = col ;
    while(x < n and y>=0){
        if(board[x][y] == 'Q')return false; 
        x++ ;
        y-- ;
    }
    return true 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there's no corresponding `operator==` that could be called for the comparison. `board[x][y]` is a `std::string`, whereas `'Q'` is a `char`. As you can see on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp), second parameter of `operator==` for comparison with `std::string` (which is `std::basic_string<char>`) can either be another `std::string` (taken by const reference) or `const char*` (C-style string). Neither of these is `char` or could be obtained through implicit conversion from `char`. In particular, see that there's [no constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) of `std::string` taking a single character.

So, the easiest solution is to compare with a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal#:%7E:text=String%20literals%20have%20static%20storage,of%20the%20string%20%22foo%22.) `"Q"` instead. This is an array object of type `const char[2]` (second character is a null terminator `'\0'`), which decays into `const char*` pointer through [array-to-pointer conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Array_to_pointer_conversion), so appropriate overload of operator can be used:

```
board[x][y] == "Q"
```

Also, note that you missed a `;` after the return statement.